# Is there a condition for $\varepsilon(n) \rightarrow 0$ so that $\frac{1}{n^{\varepsilon(n)}} \longrightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

The following question was raised in class:

> Let $\varepsilon(n)$ be a sequence such that $\varepsilon(n) > 0$ for all $n$. Is there a condition for how fast $\varepsilon(n)$ can go to $0$ such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{\varepsilon(n)}} = 0 \quad?$$

I think it might be best to write $$n^{\varepsilon(n)} = \exp( \log(n) \cdot \varepsilon(n)).$$

I it sufficient to say that we require $\varepsilon(n)$ to converge slower to $0$ than $\log(n)$? Is there a way to be more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varepsilon(n) > \frac{\omega(n)}{\log(n)}$ for any function $\omega(n)$ that goes to infinity, then $n^{\varepsilon(n)} = \exp(\log(n) \cdot \varepsilon(n))$ goes to infinity with $n$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{\varepsilon(n)}} = 0$. On the other hand, if $\varepsilon(n) < \frac{C}{\log(n)}$ for some constant $C$, then $\frac{1}{n^{\varepsilon(n)}} > e^{-C}$ and it will not converge to $0$.